# What is the total number of positive integers <300 whose digit sum is a multiple of 5?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, puzzle

As stated in the title

For one digit number there is $1$

For two digit numbers there are $27(=4+(4+5)+(4+5+5)) (sum
=5n, n=1,2,3)$ $since (5n<18)$

But I'm struggling to find the ones that are of three digits

$(sum)=5n, n=1,...,4)$$for (5n\leq20)$ (without writing out all the possible combinations).

The possible answers are $18,45,60,61$

Can someone please explain which of the above answers is the most appropriate?

Comment: Could you please replace "product" with "multiple" in the title? It is very confusing - what is "a product of 5"??

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Edited. Thanks.

Comment: It seems the answer of 59 is not in the choices.  What if there is a language issue, instead of <300 the mean <=300? Then we can include 300 and get 60.  Please check.  Thank you and Stay Safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first two digits are $0,0$ than the last digit must be $0$ or $5$. There are two such numbers.

If the first two digits are $0,1$ then the last digit must be $4$ or $9$.  There are two such number.

If the first two digits are $2$ and $7$ that then last digit must be $1$ and $6$.  There are two such numbers.

And so on.

The first two digits are $00$ to $29$, that's $30$ option and there are two options for $c$ so that there are $2*30 = 60$ such numbers.  But $000$ is not acceptable so there are $59$.

So, $59$.  Final answer.

....

But we must prove that if the first two digits are $a$ and $b$ there are exactly $2$ digits that third digit can be.

=====

ANd... if you add up $a$ and $b$ and take the remainder from dividing be $5$ (call it $r$) there are exactly $5$ possible remainders values of $r$.  For $a+b +c$ to be a multiple of $5$ then the remainder $a+b+c$ must be $0$ and the remainder of $c$ must be the opposite $r$.  That is if $r=1$ then the remainder of $c$ (call it $s$) must be $4$ and if $r=2$ then $s = 3$ and $r=3$ then $s=2$ and if $r=4$ then $s=1$ and if $r=0$ then $s = 0$.

And there are exactly $5$ possible opposite remainders that $s$ can be.  $c$ can be $s+0$ and $s+5$.

....

Putting that argument in terms of

Modular arithmetic:  If $a+b \equiv r \pmod 5$ then $c \equiv - r\pmod 5$.  As $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ are two complete residue systems there are exactly one representative for $-r$ in each set so there are two option for digit $c$.

.....

Remainder theorem:

Let $a+b = 5K + r$.  $a+b+c = 5M + 0$.  Then $c= (5M + 0)- (5K+r)=5(M-K)+r$ and $0\le c \le 9$ and $0 \le r \le 4$.  If $r=0$ then $0\le c= 5(M-K)\le 9$ so $c=0, 5$.  If $0 < r < 5$ then $0\le c = 5(M-k)-r \le 9$ then $c = 5-r$ or $c = 10-r$.

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:

1. Pad any 1 or 2-digit numbers with leading zeroes so that you need only consider 3-digit numbers.
2. If you are given the first two digits of a 3-digit number, and you know the number has a digit sum that is a multiple of 5, then how many choices do you have left for the last digit?

Note that the numbers in the question should probably range from 000 to 299.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to follow the OP's reasoning re there being 27 such two digit numbers.  Also, I was surprised by the offered answers, because I think that the answer is 59.  I infer this because if the numbers are allowed to range from 0 thru 299, rather than 1 thru 299, then I would say that the answer is 60 = 300/5.

Initially, when I considered this problem, I considered that the sum of the digits in 19 = 10 (a multiple of 5), but the sum of the digits in 20 [= 19 + 1] is not congruent mod 5 to [10 + 1].

Then, I realized that regardless of what the sum of the digits of 20 is [mod 5], in the range 20 thru 29, **there must be exactly two numbers the sum of whose digits is a multiple of 5.**  The same can be said for the 10 numbers 30 thru 39, 40 thru 49, ..., 100 thru 109, ...

This is why I conclude that if the numbers are allowed to range from 0 thru 299, there must be 60 such numbers.